# ListView.SelectedItem BindingtoSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have encountered a major problem for myself in the learning process of WPF bindings. I have to create an application that uses a Listview which look like this:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="170" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Reseller" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Reseller}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

In the codebehind file I have a property:

```
public Product seletedRow
{
    get { return m_Product; }
    set { m_Product = value; PropertyChanged("Product"); }
}
```

The goal would be to set this property to the selected row of the listView and then show the fields of this property in 4 textboxes. 
If I set this property manually from code I can display the information in the textboxes but I can't figure out how to bind the object from the ListView.SelectedItem. As far as I have found I should be using OneWayToSource binding mode but I have no idea how.

I'm also opened to other solutions, as long as I can use it in MVVM pattern.

Comment: I'm missing something. Please provide more details: What is the ItemsSource (or Items) of the ListView? Is it a collection of Product? What else do you have in the View Model? Do you want to support editing of a collection of Product by the user? If so, why don't you use DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to do something like this. That way you don't even need any code-behind.

```
{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItem.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

You'll need to assign ListView a name like this.

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
```

It would look something like this.

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
    <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="170" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Reseller" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Reseller}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=SelectedItem.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Edit:

If you wan't to expand on the logic you probably want to look into using `ACB`, as with `ACB` you could do something like this.

```
acb:CommandBehavior.Event="SelectedItemChanged"
acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding SelectedItemChanged}"
acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

This would essentially allow you to store the specific `SelectedItem` each time you choose a new item on the list.

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/

Comment: I know I can do it that way, BUT later on I have to be able to update the Model from a Button click. Now if I take this example and let's assume I have the button, how will I add the CommandParameters from the textboxes?
I can't say that Path=SelectedItem because that will be the old value. And I can't use TwoWayBinding because the criteria is that the Listview only updates after the Button's execute command finiehed.

Comment: That's why you have the `PropertyChanged`. You can simply manually update the `Product` in code, and both the `ListView` and the `TextBox` should pick up on the updates. Although, you may need to use something like a `ICollectionView` to push the update to the `ListView` manually.

Comment: Well I still have the following problem: If I select an item in the list the textboxes will contain the necessary data. I change the product details in the textboxes, !!I don't click to the Button!!. I select another row, and the previous row which should not get updated did get updated immediately; however it should only get updated once the button has been clicked.

Comment: Quite similar to this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ptmujeeb/wpf-mvvm-pattern-a-simple-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

Comment: I think you should use `ACB` (AttachedCommandBehavior) for this if you are using `MVVM`. I'll update my example.

Comment: No. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I either have to bind the SelectedItem to a property; alternatively I'd have to use MultiBinding. I'll show you why:
 UpdateCommand takes a Product object as parameter which comes from the textboxes and not the listView.

Either I make a MultiBinding like:
<Button.CommandParameters>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MybinderObject}">
        <Binding ElementName="txtID" Path="Text" />
        ....
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameters>

It throws an exception that the current string was not in current format tho.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. I'm sure there are many solutions, but the easiest is to use ACB in this case. It allows you to store a SelectedItem object in your ViewModel that you use whenever you need to update the data. An example would be that you have variables stored from your TextBoxes in your ViewModel, and then bind a function to your Update button. Then simply update the objects on the SelectedItem using those variables. The advantage with the ACB is that it's a function, so you can manually update the TextBoxes when selecting an item, making sure that updates to your TextBox does not carry over.

Comment: This really makes my life easier. Thanks for your help. :)